# Создание doc документа

Tags: qt, docx

Попытался создать документ с таблицей и текстом . Но столкнулся с проблемой что, библиотека *docxFactory* не способна работать  с файлом от начала до конца и по этому там требуется участие рук человека . Мне это не устраивает так как  от меня требуется создание программы в которой при нажатии на "пуск" создавался отчет с таблицами и текстом.

Есть ли простые библиотеки на `C++` что бы работать с doc, docx, rtf, файлами ???

Comment: Попробуйте рассмотреть вывод ваших таблиц в документ html.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Openoffice\Libreoffice для преобразования формата документа.
Для начала создаем документ в легкопрограммируемом формате HTML или RTF, затем
конвертировать в Документ Майкрософт Офис

```
soffice --headless --convert-to <extension> <path+file>
```

В случае с Убунтой можно использовать зависимости и `unoconv`, в случае с Виндовс всё сложнее.

Через IF_DEFINED переписать кусок кода специально под сборки для разных платформ, в которых реализовать взаимодействие с конкретным офисом - очень распространен Майкрософт Офис(тут через активХ), но часто встречается и Опенофис(тут через soffice, но есть и другие варианты интеграции).

Answer (score 0):

Формат doc для подобных задач будет сложно реализовать поэтому большинство программ используют экспорт в Excel. 
Я бы рекомендовал вам использовать именно этот формат и например библиотеку для qt [qxlse](http://www.qtsoftware.de/vertrieb/db/qtxls_e.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал вывод в PDF, если это отчет "бумажного" формата.

А ещё часто встречал "грязный" способ: делается вывод в html, а имя файла указывается .doc. Таким образом файл связан с текстовым редактором, при открытии исправляется.

Comment: Можете подсказать как делать вывод в html. Просто я создал строку

Comment: Можете подсказать как делать вывод в html. Просто я создал строку в QString и заполнил текстом с таблицей .docx сослался на ошибку а .doc открыл но без возможности редактировать текст

Comment: @timob256 вот как с доком и должно было получится, раньше редактировался. похоже много зависит от версий. Оставлю еще один ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону ActiveX

```
QAxObject *W = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
```

Comment: Программа должна работать не только в винде но и на убунте .  п.с. ActiveX  им в основном можно читать как записывать я вообще не разобрался.

Comment: если нужно кроссплотформенное решение, может воспользоваться .odt ? в qt  работает из коробки

Comment: > может воспользоваться .odt ? в qt работает из коробки.        Нет не может единственное что может только простейший байтовый вывод (txt фаил )

Comment: Извините был не прав, может , но русский язык почемуто не тображает (точнее знаю почему там он через 2 редактора проходит но при этом в каждом своя кодировка

Comment: для решения подобной задачи я использовал поля MergeField  в .Doc вставка - экспресс блоки - поле . Создавал шаблон пустой файл с данными которые не менялись а где надо вставлял поля а после искал в документе эти поля и заменял на нужные, есть вариант задавать значение эти полям

Answer (score 0):

Может вас устроит вариант с `QTextDocument` и `QTextDocumentWriter`, которыe позволяет экспортировать документ в форматах - `PDF`, `html`, `odt`. Если необходим формат именно `.doc`, тогда есть такой костыль: Экспортируйте документ в формат `html`, но с расширением `.doc`. MsWord открывает, но теряется выравнивание